# Podio Webhook API: What Are The Ref Types?

Tags: webhooks, podio

Looking at the docs for Podio webhook API, I'm seeing reference to a `ref_type` and `ref_id`. However, there is no documentation as to what the `ref_type`s are. In attempting to create a normal `item.create` webhook, I'm unsure what to put here.

What are the types of `ref_type`s?

Documentation here:
https://podio-community.github.io/podio-php/webhooks/
https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/create-hook-215056

Answer (score 0):

Podio web-hooks are described in more details at: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks

`ref_type` could be:

1. app
2. app_field
3. space

For most widely used `item.create` web-hook, you would want to use `app` as ref_type, with `<app_id>` as ref_id.

Examples on how to use Podio web-hooks are here: https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks